# Make for objtool in Ubuntu 20.04 fails because of missing Build.include file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile, driver

I'm trying to build and install the [DisplayLink driver](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/684649-how-to-install-displaylink-software-on-ubuntu) on a recently upgraded Ubuntu 20.04 laptop, so that I can make use of a Dell D3100 docking station to drive two external monitors via DisplayPorts. I had previously installed this driver successfully on the same laptop when it was running Ubuntu 18.04, and was able to detect and use the additional monitors (albeit with the occasional black screen).

I've downloaded the latest 5.2.14 driver installer from the [download page](https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu), but this time when I run as sudo it fails due to some sort of misconfiguration or missing file/build folder, with the following showing up in the make log file:

`/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-24-lowlatency/tools/build/Makefile.build:37: /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-24-lowlatency/tools/build/Build.include: No such file or directory`

There is indeed no /usr/src/linux-headers-/tools/build/Build.include file, but I'm not sure why, and whether I'm missing a package I need?

Output from running the installer:

```
bric@home:~/System/DisplayLink$ sudo ./displaylink-driver-5.2.14.run 
Verifying archive integrity...  100%   All good.
Uncompressing DisplayLink Linux Driver 5.2.14  100%  
DisplayLink Linux Software 5.2.14 install script called: install
Distribution discovered: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Installing
Configuring EVDI DKMS module
Registering EVDI kernel module with DKMS
Building EVDI kernel module with DKMS
ERROR (code 3): Failed to build evdi/5.2.14. Consult /var/lib/dkms/evdi/5.2.14/build/make.log for details..
```

Directory shows there is no Build.include:

```
$ ls -la /usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-24-lowlatency/tools/build/
total 40
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Apr 18 06:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 33 root root 4096 Apr 18 06:27 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr 18 06:27 feature
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1066 Nov 25 11:32 Makefile
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 3998 Nov 25 11:32 Makefile.build
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 8295 Nov 25 11:32 Makefile.feature
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  257 Nov 25 11:32 Makefile.include
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Apr 18 06:27 tests
```

The make.log file is attached below, let me know if anything else is helpful.

[Make.log](https://pastebin.com/dabcTz9F)

Any suggestions for what I am missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems that the problem was being caused by invalid directory instructions in the Makefile of the DisplayLink driver, as I eventually found [here](https://github.com/DisplayLink/evdi/issues/172#issuecomment-561964789) (though this refers to an rpm release of the driver).

It looks as though when I've upgraded to the 5.4 kernel, this also changed the way that Makefiles are parsed, such that any SUBDIRS= parameters are ignored, leaving the instructions attempting to run make in the linux-headers/tools/build folder instead of the kernel module folder.

As the discussion thread linked above describes, the solution is to replace `SUBDIRS=blah` with `M=blah` in the Makefile, in addition to applying another [patch](https://crazy.dev.frugalware.org/evdi-1.6.4-kernel-5.4.x.patch) to update source files that refer to `<linux/reservation.h>` to instead refer to the newer `<linux/dma-resv.h>`.

When I updated the DisplayLink driver 5.2 source with these patches, I was able to successfully build the evdi kernel module and connect my other monitors through the DisplayPorts on the dock. Hopefully this helps anyone else, until the next DisplayLink driver is released!

Comment: interesting answer thanks! I cannot figure out how I'll force the displaylink installation to use the patch, can you clearify that too? :)

Comment: @fabianski - I extracted from the installer .run file into a temporary directory with `./displaylink-driver-5.2.14.run --noexec --keep --target <dir>`. Inside this directory, there is a tar.gz archive with the sources used to build the evdi module, so I extracted these (ie, `tar zxvf evdi-5.2.14-src.tar.gz -C sources/`), altered them in line with the patch, then created a replacement tar.gz using the modified files. Then I ran the installer directly, via `sudo ./displaylink-installer.sh install`. Hope that helps!

Comment: Oh, also, the thing to be careful of is that the uninstaller (`./displaylink-installer.sh uninstall`) will remove certain key files from that installer subdirectory, so you can't immediately install again without restoring them from the .run file.

Comment: ah nice, I tried it almost like that but in a slightly different way. will try that, thanks!

Comment: @BrettRichards forgive my ignorance, but can you elaborate the command I'd need to "alter them in line with the patch"? Tried a few things and proved I don't know what I'm doing...

Comment: @fabianski, what was that slightly different way? I reproduced steps adviced by BrettRichards and still fail to build. Done SUBDIR-to-M substitution. In extracting evdi-5.2.14-src.tar.gz to sources/ I copied patch (crazy.dev.frugalware.org/evdi-1.6.4-kernel-5.4.x.patch) and via patch command applied to all c and h files, then compressed again and run installer without success ... Got errors:
`include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing`
`/var/lib/dkms/evdi/5.2.14/build/evdi_drv.h:23:10: fatal error: linux/reservation.h: No such file or directory`
I run Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @BrettRichards you're probably looking for something like `$ patch < /location/to/downloaded/patch/patchname.patch`

Comment: @micholeodon a way that did not work and won't work for anyone.. in terms of your error: I had to remove the existing evdi files to make the installation work `/var/lib/dkms/evdi` maybe that's solving the issue already.

Comment: Not helped sadly :(

Comment: Mh, maybe there is one step or a part of a step missing. You could open another question that contains the interesting parts of the files you altered so that one can see if there is something missing.

Comment: Finally I fixed. Found advice on https://www.displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=67007 to install drivers for debian, cloned https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/displaylink-debian. Installed sudo `apt-get install libdrm-dev`. Then followed install guide on display-link-debian git page. Finally fixed mouse flickering using advice from https://displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=66577 
I needed to comment out intel config in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf (if one have it). Now external monitor works fine. Maybe installing libdrm was the real solution, without need to install debian driver.